# Saving collection of items to the sqlite table

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite

When i had autoIncrement id in my sqlite table, i used this code to insert or update the item:

```
        public string SaveItem(MyClass item)
    {
        if (item.id != null)
        {
            database.Update(item);
            return item.id;
        }
        else
        {
            database.Insert(item);
            return item.id;
        }
    }
```

Now id isn't AutoIncrement (i have my own unique id).
How can I check if the item exists or not in this case (item.id != null) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if item exists first:

```
    public string SaveItem(MyClass item) {
    if (item != null && item.id != null) {
        database.Update(item);
        return item.id;
    } else {
        // Do you still want to insert invalid items?
        database.Insert(item);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i'm going to save a lot of items, i should use that code for each iteration?

Comment: public bool SaveItemsCollection(IEnumerable<MyClass> itemsCollection)
        {
            database.BeginTransaction();
            ....
            database.Commit();
        }

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis!

Comment: I read the answer one more time and i see it's not the desicion. Maybe it was my fault (i gave incorrect question). I want to understand how can i check if item exists in the sqlite table or not.

Comment: post another question

Comment: Dennis, i've found the desicion: SQLiteConnection object has InsertOrReplace and InsertAll methods.